# How to create a dynamic menu drawer with dropdown (infinite nesting)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, quasar

I want to create a nested menu drawer, where I could insert menu inside menu, creating n levels of submenus, and subitems.
Something that would look like this:

```
            Menu v
                --Submenu ^
                    ----Submenu v 
                        ------Subitem 
                        ------Subitem
                    ----Subitem
                    ----Subitem
                --Submenu v
                --Subitem
            Menu ^
```

Ideally this should be rendered from a database table, where I could associate to users.

```
            menu(
                id
                name
                icon
                route
                is_active
                menu (references another table)
            );
```

How to render this in the html correctly? And is this the best approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what is being asked. Is this statement correct?: "I want only certain elements at a certain time to be displayed based on the contents of my data."

Comment: Yeah, based on the data, it should render the menu items, and subitems ( I think another "is_dropdown" flag should be added)